# Faster way of upgrading postgres to 10 from 9.5

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I am trying to test the migration of postgres to 10 from 9.5

On trying in a test DB of size 490 GB in one postgres node it is taking about 18 mins. The command I used

```
sudo -H -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_upgrade \
   -b /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin \
   -B /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin \
   -d /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql0 \
   -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/data/postgresql0 \
   -o ' -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf' \
   -O ' -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf' -k
```

Is there any faster way of doing this?

Comment: 18 min for half a TB doesn't feel slow to me. The other option would be the to do the (complicated) upgrade through pg_logical replication, which advertises minimal downtime.

Comment: 18 minutes is pretty slow when using link mode.  How many objects (tables, indexes, sequences, etc.) do you have in the database?  How long does it take to do `pg_dump -s` ?  How long does it take restore said schema-only dump into a fresh new database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a script for loading junk data in postgres. It created a lot of databases (about 500). So this was causing `pg_dump` to take so much time.

After populating only the relevant database (about 100 GB) I am seeing good performance (about 5 second with `-k` option).

Comment: But this `-k` is already used in the command you've posted in your question. Of course `-k` is faster as it implies no data copy between versions migrated, it only moves data files from older instance to newer. But also lets older version unusable, so downgrade is not an option when using `-k`.